# Very minor css bug on area51 proposals pagination

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

You can see the border on the "prev", "..." and "next"

Comment: Aha! I see you transmogrified to a parallel universe to thwart my evil plan. Fiendish cunning.

Comment: @The Proposer Haha, you may still be there, but the proposal isn't. My plan worked!!! (Shame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe you noticed that. I had to squint to see it, but sure enough, there was a faint 1px white border. It's gone now.